# Why can't I use u-substitution to solve for $\int 1/(\sin x+\cos x)~ dx$?

Tags: calculus, integration

I checked my work on an online calculator and it's wrong. Can someone explain why I can't solve it this way and how do I solve it?

$$\int{\frac{1}{\sin x+ \cos x}dx}$$

$$\rightarrow\space \int (\sin x+ \cos x)^{-1}~dx $$

$$ u = \sin x + \cos x $$

$$du = (\cos x - \sin x) \space dx$$

$$\rightarrow\space \frac{1}{(\cos x- \sin x)}\int(\cos x- \sin x)(u)^{-1}dx $$

$${\rightarrow}\space \frac{1}{(\cos x- \sin x)}\int (u)^{-1}du $$

$${\rightarrow}\space \frac{1}{(\cos x- \sin x)} \ln \vert u \vert + C $$

$$ ∴ \frac{\ln \vert \sin x+ \cos x \vert}{(\cos x- \sin x)} + C $$

Comment: You can't pull a non-constant outside of the integral.

Comment: I understand. Thank you.

Comment: Yeah, if you *could* pull a non-constant out of an integral, you would just have $\int{f(x) ~dx}= f(x)\int{dx} = f(x)(x + C)$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's try this: Recall that $$\sin(A+B)=\sin(A)\cos(B)+\sin(B)\cos(A).$$   We can write $$\sin(x)+\cos(x) = \sqrt{2}\Bigl[\sin(x)\cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}+\cos(x)\cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\Bigr].$$ Since $\sin(\pi/4)=\cos(\pi/4)=1/\sqrt{2}$, this becomes $$\sqrt{2}\Bigl[\sin(x)\cos(\pi/4)+\cos(x)\sin(\pi/4)\Bigr]=\sqrt{2}\sin(x+\pi/4).$$

Then $$\frac{1}{\sin(x)+\cos(x)}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}\sin(x+\pi/4)}=\frac{\csc(x+\pi/4)}{\sqrt{2}}.$$

This should get you far enough to finish.